# OpenSSL to create CMS from Message Digest directly

Tags: openssl

In order to start generating CMS you need to provide "data" for signing
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/CMS_sign.html

My problem is that I have already the Message Digest (pre-calculated SHA256 hash of the "data"), and it is not required openssl to calculate the HASH during the signing, anyone know how I can use openssl to generate CMS from a pre-calculated SHA256 hash? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Looking at the sources for [`apps/cms.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/cms.c), it looks like you need to use `CMS_set1_eContentType` with `NID_pkcs7_digest`. I'm not sure how difficult that is in practice. Usually its a bad idea to blindly sign a hash of a document. Usually you want the original document so you can ensure you know what you are applying the signature to.

Comment: Thanks! Let me check...